# Loading library (lib*.so) file in python2.4

Tags: python, linux

How can I load a library in Python and run a few of its methods available with the library.
I am aware of ctypes but its not available in python2.4. 
Is there any equivalent module for python2.4? And how do I run a few of its methods available in library.

Comment: you can set PYTHONPATH to point to the library, and directly import it in the code

Comment: @avasal I think OP means the .so file is not a python module, just a regular .so library.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install ctypes via easy_install on python 2.3/2.4

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ctypes

Answer (score 0):

Although ctypes was only added to the standard Python distribution in version 2.5, it is [available for earlier versions](http://www.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/), including version 2.4. Your only alternative to installing ctypes is to write a [Python extension](http://docs.python.org/extending/).